# Is there a way of retrieving the contact list from Win Phone 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is there a way of retrieving the contact list from Win Phone 8  like it happens in Android.
Basically i need to implement an SMS sending feature from inside the application and for it to happen, i need to show the users existing contacts.
using C# +XAML +WP8.

Answer (score 1):

There is sample on msdn for [contact and calender](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Contacts-and-Calendar-9fce5e26)
And here is the walk through for accessing [contacts and calender](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286414%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This MSDN post details in length how to search/access contact details from the phone: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286416%28v=vs.92%29.aspx